# R how to determine the largest possible tree with Rpart and Tree

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I want to determine the largest possible tree with rpart and tree packages. I created trees with these two packages but I do not know how to reach the largest possible tree. Anyone knows?

Comment: Could you provide an example with associated data?

Comment: X_rpart=rpart(type~.,method="class",data = rawdata_trainingset, control=rpart.control(minsplit = 1)). This is my tree creation code and it gives 8 node tree but I want  to reach the largest possible tree with given data. For instance, can I create 15 node tree with a given data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to set the number of the desired node via some parameters, however, you can increase the complexity of your tree by decreasing the `cp` argument of `rpart.control` function. Like this:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
data(iris)
l <- lapply(c(0.1,0.01,0.001), function(x){
  X_rpart = rpart(
    Species ~ .,
    method = "class",
    data = iris,
    control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1,cp=x)
  )
})

for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  rpart.plot(l[[i]])
}
```

You can see that the smaller `cp` the greater the number of nodes will be in the final tree. Here the plots for the 3 iterations:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment:))). I'll try it, I hope it will work. Thx a lot:)